# Classical Field Theory Using Geometry

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, field-theory, topology

I would like to know if there are good introductory courses on Classical Field Theory taught in a differential geometry approach yet one doesn't need a background in those mathematical subjects but will be able to follow as the course will be complete and one will learn the mathematics on the way as the course proceeds.

Books, lecture notes, video lectures will be really cool.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you want, but it does go over some classical field theory and good chuck of differential geometry.

http://www.gravity-and-light.org/lectures

Comment: I thik this will do just fine. I know classical field theory already just not in the DG language. I just need the DG language in a Physics perspective. Tganks.